# bloquear a gravação de dados offline Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Tenho essa função que realiza a gravação de dados no Firebase:

```
addPedido(pedido: Pedido) {
  this.pedidosCollection.add({
     ...pedido,
     log_criado: this.timestamp
  })
}
```

Caso não tenha conexão com a internet essa função salva os dados offline para posteriormente quando online parear os dados com o BD.

Como eu poderia fazer para bloquear essa transação quando a conexão estiver offline?

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir resolver com fromCache

service.ts

```
async addPedid(pedido: Pedido) {
  return  await this.empresasCollection.doc<Empresa>(pedido.id_empresa).get().toPromise().then(
    snapshot => {
      let retorno = 'erro'
      if(snapshot.metadata.fromCache){
        console.log('está utizando cache')
        retorno = 'offline';
      } else {
        this.pedidosCollection.add({
          ...pedido,
            log_criado: this.timestamp
        }).catch((erro: any) => {
          console.log('erro 33', erro);
          return 'erro';
        });
        retorno = 'online';
      }
    return retorno
  })
}
```

component.ts

```
async salvaPedido(){
   const returnSalvo = await this.pedidoService.addPedido(this.pedido);
   console.log(returnSalvo)
}
```